# How To Get Financial Year Month(April to March) based on Year in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I need to get Financial Year Month(April to March) based on Year in Postgres Query...

Like if passing 2022 then I need to get(12 month list) April-2022 to March-2023 month list.

I have tried using EXTRACT() Function date to year but not getting exact result.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT to_char(t, 'Month-yyyy') AS financial_month
from generate_series(
             date 'yyyy-04-01'::date, -- Replace yyyy with your desired year
             date 'yyyy-04-01'::date + interval '1 year - 1 day',
             interval '1 month'
         ) t
```

This query generates a series of dates starting from April 1st of the specified year and ending on March 31st of the following year (a financial year). It then uses the to_char function to format these dates as "Month-YYYY" (e.g., "April-2022", "May-2022", ..., "March-2023").

Comment: Thanks @Muhammad Muminov, it's work for me,

Answer (score 0):

You can use this generally to generate the list for the financial year by changing the year:

```
SELECT
    to_char(start_date, 'Month-YYYY') AS financial_month
FROM (
    SELECT 
        generate_series(
            date 'year-04-01',
            date 'year-03-01',
            interval '1 month'
        ) AS start_date
) AS months;
```

I have replaced year to 2022 and 2023 to get the list you wanted in your example:

```
SELECT
    to_char(start_date, 'Month-YYYY') AS financial_month
FROM (
    SELECT 
        generate_series(
            date '2022-04-01',
            date '2023-03-01',
            interval '1 month'
        ) AS start_date
) AS months;
```

You will the following output:

```
 financial_month 
-----------------
 April-2022
 May-2022
 June-2022
 July-2022
 August-2022
 September-2022
 October-2022
 November-2022
 December-2022
 January-2023
 February-2023
 March-2023
(12 rows)
```

Comment: Good to hear! Feel free to upvote and mark an answer as accepted if it solved your problem!

Answer (score 0):

You can as well try this query to get Financial Year Month based on Year

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(generate_series, 'Month-YYYY')
FROM generate_series(
    DATE '2022-04-01',
    DATE '2022-04-01' + INTERVAL '1 year - 1 day',
    INTERVAL '1 month'
) AS generate_series;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IF V_MONTH='ALL' THEN

V_YEAR_MONTH_FROM:=(SUBSTR(V_YEAR,1,4)-1|| '04') :: NUMERIC; V_YEAR_MONTH_TO:= (SUBSTR(V_YEAR,6,4)-1|| '03'):: NUMERIC;

ELSE

IF V_MONTH IN ('01','02', '03') THEN

V_YEAR_MONTH_FROM:=(SUBSTR(V_YEAR,6,4)||V_MONTH):: NUMERIC; V_YEAR_MONTH_TO:= (SUBSTR(V_YEAR,6,4)||V_MONTH):: NUMERIC;

ELSE

V_YEAR_MONTH_FROM:=(SUBSTR(V_YEAR,1,4)||V_MONTH):: NUMERIC; V_YEAR_MONTH_TO:=(SUBSTR(V_YEAR,1,4) || V_MONTH):: NUMERIC;

END IF;

END IF;
```

Comment: Please describe the effect of what you propose and why helps to solve the problem. Consider learning about formatting, https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting Try for [answer].